# Haskell zmq & protobuf message forwarding

Tags: haskell, zeromq, protocol-buffers

I wrote a test program (and first "real" Haskell program!) that receives a zmq request on 1 socket, and forwards part of that message to another socket.

There are a 2 things I specifically don't like:

- I couldn't figure out a way to build a protobuf message without specifying *every* field.  This is especially annoying for fields like `failure_message`, which I had to set to `Nothing`
- I'm not a fan of the lazyToStrictBS conversion

Is there any way to avoid these?  Also, any other things I should fix? I would be shocked if there were no other issues.

The code:

```
module Main where

import System.ZMQ4.Monadic  
import Control.Monad (forever)  
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack, unpack)  
import qualified Data.ByteString as ByteString (ByteString, concat)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS (ByteString, toChunks)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

import Text.ProtocolBuffers.WireMessage (messageGet)
import Text.ProtocolBuffers.WireMessage (messagePut)

import ProtoMsg.ForwardRequest (ForwardRequest)
import ProtoMsg.ForwardResponse
import ProtoMsg.ReqResponse (ReqResponse)
import ProtoMsg.Status
import ProtoMsg.Retort


lazyToStrictBS :: LBS.ByteString -> ByteString.ByteString
lazyToStrictBS x = ByteString.concat $ LBS.toChunks x

main :: IO ()  
main =  
    runZMQ $ do
        repSocket <- socket Rep
        bind repSocket "tcp://*:9000"

        pubSocket <- socket Pub
        bind pubSocket "tcp://*:9001"

        liftIO $ putStrLn "Ready"
        forever $ do
            msg <- receive repSocket
            (liftIO.putStrLn.unwords) ["Received request:", unpack msg]

            let repMsg = ProtoMsg.ForwardResponse.ForwardResponse {
                header = ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.ReqResponse {
                    message_id = Nothing,
                    user_id = Nothing,
                    request_id = Nothing,
                    ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.status = Just ProtoMsg.Status.OK,
                    failure_message = Nothing
                }
            }
            let respMsg = ProtoMsg.Retort.Retort {
                status = Just ProtoMsg.Status.OK,
                failure_message = Nothing
            }
            send repSocket [] (lazyToStrictBS (messagePut respMsg))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you have used `hprotoc` to generate Haskell modules then you should be able to use [`defaultValue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/protocol-buffers-2.2.0/docs/Text-ProtocolBuffers-Basic.html#v:defaultValue) and optional fields will be assigned to `Nothing` by default i.e.

```
header = ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.ReqResponse {
    message_id = Nothing,
    user_id = Nothing,
    request_id = Nothing,
    ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.status = Just ProtoMsg.Status.OK,
    failure_message = Nothing
}
```

could be replaced with

```
header = defaultValue {
    ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.status = Just ProtoMsg.Status.OK
}
```

2) Instead of your `lazyToStrictBS` you could use the standard function [toStrict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:toStrict) in the [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) package